# Is there a faster alternative for DLookup to fill unbound text fields on a form?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm using DLookup to search for a field in a table. It runs correctly, but is slow. Is there anything I can do to speed it up?

Here's my existing code:

```
Me(k1) = Dlookup("[KLant]", "[Planning_tbl02]", "[Plek#]=" & p & " AND [datum]='" & Me(k4) & "'" & " AND [bezet_ochtend]='" & "bezet" & "'")
```

Comment: It depends where you're using it. Are you putting this formula in a control on a form or report or are you using it within a query?

Comment: Please edit your question to show all relevant code - is this run in a loop? In which event? -- P.S. Hi there! :)

Comment: Hi @Andre! Why do the names of your controls come from variables (`k1` and `k4`)?

Answer (score 0):

Add *indexes* in the table on the fields you filter on.

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own lookup code that opens a recordset and finds the desired value, for example:

```
Dim strCriteria As String, strQuery As String

strCriteria = _
    BuildCriteria("[Plek#]", dbLong, p) & " And " & _
    BuildCriteria("[datum]", dbDate, Me(k4)) & " And " & _
    BuildCriteria("[bezet_ochtend]", dbText, """bezet""")

strQuery = "SELECT [KLant] FROM [Planning_tbl02] WHERE " & strCriteria

With CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strQuery, dbOpenForwardOnly)
    If Not .EOF Then
        Me(k1) = ![KLant]
    Else
        Me(k1) = Null
    End If
    .Close
End With
```

**Added:**

After reviewing your code, I found that the statements for odd and even values of `k2` doesn't differ much, so I was able to simplify the code a little. Also, I found that `k4` changes only for odd values of `k2` which halves the number of database searches. This means of course, that there will be no difference in the afternoon. Finally, as promised in my comment, I reduced the number of recordsets to 30 and implemented searches with `FindFirst` for the dates. Here's my result:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

    Dim p As Integer, k2 As Integer
    Dim k1 As String, k1_prev As String, k4 As String
    Dim r1 As Integer, g As Integer, b As Integer
    Dim strCriteria As String, strQuery As String

    For p = 1 To 30

        If r1 < 49 Then r1 = 255 Else r1 = r1 - 49
        If g > 203 Then g = 100 Else g = g + 52
        If b < 127 Then b = 160 Else b = b - 127

        strQuery = "SELECT [KLant], [datum] FROM [Planning_tbl02] WHERE " & _
            BuildCriteria("[Plek#]", dbLong, p) & " And " & _
            BuildCriteria("[bezet_ochtend]", dbText, """bezet""")

        With CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strQuery, dbOpenDynaset)
            For k2 = 1 To 26

                k1_prev = k1
                k1 = "pl" & p & "_" & k2

                If k2 Mod 2 = 1 Then
                    k4 = "calday" & (k2 + 1) \ 2
                    .FindFirst BuildCriteria("[datum]", dbDate, Me(k4))
                    If .NoMatch Then Me(k1) = Null Else Me(k1) = ![klant]
                Else
                    Me(k1) = Me(k1_prev)
                End If

                If Not IsNull(Me(k1)) Then
                    If k2 = 1 Then
                        Me(k1).BackColor = RGB(r1, g, b)
                    Else
                        If Me(k1) <> Me(k1_prev) Then 'next color
                            If r1 < 49 Then r1 = 255 Else r1 = r1 - 49
                            If g > 203 Then g = 100 Else g = g + 52
                            If b < 127 Then b = 160 Else b = b - 127
                        End If
                        Me(k1).BackColor = RGB(r1, g, b)
                    End If
                End If

            Next
            .Close
        End With
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: True, you can do this, but  a dlookup() vs a whole reocrdset peforms the same. The BIG issue is when using a dlookup() in side of a query, or say on a continues form - that's like executing a whole recordset + query. So it not really that dlookup (or dcount() etc.) is slower then a "whole" process or create a query + reocrdset. The main problem is  dlookup() can be a rope to hang ones' self with, because it can be easily abused.

Comment: Dear @Albert, I can't believe to read from you (I mean YOU...) that "dlookup" and "recordset" perform the same. Of course, using `DLookup` in a query would **really** be a pain, and joining the lookup-table would be much more efficient, but in this case, reading `Me` in the original question, we have to assume that it's VBA code "behind a form".

Comment: Right, but if that form or in fact code is only pulling the one record with dlookup(). THAT SINGLE dlookup() will run the SAME as the whole bit of reocrdset code posted. You will NOT improve speed by swapping that single dlookup() with some VBA recordset code as posted to pull the same single one value. They run the SAME in terms of speed. My point about dlookup() in a query is of course VERY bad. That point is not relevant to this example - and the point STILL remains that dlookup() to get one value vs that posted reocrdset code will run the SAME speed. So yes, I assume VBA in a form here.

Comment: I've used already some code of Wolfgang and it's a little bit faster, thanks.
But it's now 6 seconds instead of 10 seconds and I want to have max 2 seconds if possible.

Comment: Hi @Andre, I added an additional example. Please have a look and give it a try.

Comment: Hi @Wolfgang, thanks for the code!
I've tried, but I get an error what I can not solve by myself.

Comment: Hallo @Andre, sorry to hear that, but if you don't tell me more about the error, I can't help either.

Comment: Hi @Wolfgang, I get an error with below line:

'.FindFirst BuildCriteria("'[datum]'", dbText, Me(k4))'
I get the error: Error 3070 runtime error the Microsoft Access-database-engine can not recognize datum as a valid fieldname or expression

So, I've changed the code as above and now it works without any error, but the fields are empty, while I expect some data.

Is there something with one of the 3 criteria's?

many thanks!

Comment: Hi @Andre, ok, I see. We both made a mistake. You used `dbText` instead of `dbDate`, and I forgot the field in my query. I have corrected my code.

Comment: Hi @Wolfgang, great! It works properly now. Many thanks for your effort and time!

Comment: @Andre, you are welcome. May I ask if the speed has increased a little?

Comment: @Wolfgang, yes the speed is increased from 9 seconds to 2,5 seconds!  I've also added some indexes in the table what helps as well.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your replys.
It's a form with +/- 780 unbound textfields which should be filled with data from a table.
I build a program for a little camping and this form is a sort of planning for the available places per day. So they have 30 places and they want to see 2 weeks, so a lot of fields, because they aslo want the day split in morning and and afternoon.
I know, it's maybe not the correct way to progam, but my knowledge is not bigger at the moment :-(

So, if somebody has a good suggestion, I will really appreciate that.

See below for the complete code, it's a loop in a loop.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

For p = 1 To 30
k2 = 1
k3 = 1

r1 = r1 - 49
g = g + 52
b = b - 127

If r1 < 0 Then r1 = 255
If g < 0 Then g = 200
If b < 0 Then b = 160

If r1 > 255 Then r1 = 31
If g > 255 Then g = 100
If b > 255 Then b = 56

For k2 = 1 To 26

k1 = "pl" & p & "_" & k2
k4 = "calday" & k3

If r1 < 0 Then r1 = 255
If g < 0 Then g = 200
If b < 0 Then b = 160

If r1 > 255 Then r1 = 31
If g > 255 Then g = 100
If b > 255 Then b = 56

If k2 Mod 2 = 1 Then

Dim strCriteria As String, strQuery As String
strCriteria = _
BuildCriteria("[Plek#]", dbLong, p) & " And " & _
BuildCriteria("[datum]", dbDate, Me(k4)) & " And " & _
BuildCriteria("[bezet_ochtend]", dbText, """bezet""")

strQuery = "SELECT [KLant] FROM [Planning_tbl02] WHERE " & strCriteria

With CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strQuery, dbOpenForwardOnly)
If Not .EOF Then
 Me(k1) = ![klant]
 Else
Me(k1) = Null
End If
 .Close
End With 

If k2 = 1 Then

If Me(k1).Value <> "" Then
Me(k1).BackColor = RGB(r1, g, b)
End If
End If

If k2 - 1 > 0 Then

If Me(k1).Value <> "" And IsNull(Me("pl" & p & "_" & (k2 - 1)).Value) Then
Me(k1).BackColor = RGB(r1, g, b)
End If
End If

If k2 - 1 > 0 Then

If Me(k1).Value <> "" And Me("pl" & p & "_" & k2) = Me("pl" & p & "_" & (k2 - 1))Then
Me(k1).BackColor = RGB(r1, g, b)
End If
End If

If k2 - 1 > 0 Then

If Me("pl" & p & "_" & k2) <> Me("pl" & p & "_" & (k2 - 1)) Then
r1 = r1 - 49
g = g + 52
b = b - 127

Me(k1).BackColor = RGB(r1, g, b)
End If
End If
End If

If k2 Mod 2 <> 1 Then
strCriteria = _
BuildCriteria("[Plek#]", dbLong, p) & " And " & _
BuildCriteria("[datum]", dbDate, Me(k4)) & " And " & _
BuildCriteria("[bezet_ochtend]", dbText, """bezet""")

strQuery = "SELECT [KLant] FROM [Planning_tbl02] WHERE " & strCriteria

With CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strQuery, dbOpenForwardOnly)
If Not .EOF Then
 Me(k1) = ![klant]
 Else
Me(k1) = Null
End If
.Close
End With

If Me(k1).Value <> "" And IsNull(Me("pl" & p & "_" & (k2 - 1)).Value) Then
Me(k1).BackColor = RGB(r1, g, b)
End If

If Me(k1).Value <> "" And Me("pl" & p & "_" & k2) = Me("pl" & p & "_" & (k2 - 1))Then
Me(k1).BackColor = RGB(r1, g, b)
End If

If k2 - 1 > 0 Then
If Me(k1).Value <> "" And Me("pl" & p & "_" & k2) <> Me("pl" & p & "_" & (k2 - 1)) Then
Me(k1).BackColor = RGB(r1, g, b)
End If
End If

If k2 - 1 > 0 Then

If Me("pl" & p & "_" & k2) <> Me("pl" & p & "_" & (k2 - 1)) Then
r1 = r1 - 49
g = g + 52
b = b - 127

If r1 < 0 Then r1 = 255
If g < 0 Then g = 200
If b < 0 Then b = 160

Me(k1).BackColor = RGB(r1, g, b)
End If
End If
End If

If k2 Mod 2 <> 1 Then
k3 = k3 + 1
End If

Next

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: If `k2` is even, it is always greater than 1. `r1` and `b` both can't become greater than 255, `g` can't become less than 0.

Comment: that code is needed to give the textbox a backround color. It has to check if the box is empty or a different customer. So every customer has another background color to get it more visible. But without this code, it is still slow

Comment: Ok, then it will probably be more efficient to reduce the lengthy code a bit, change the order of the loops, open only one recordset per `datum` and use `FindFirst` to find the *place*. I'll give you an example later. Also, create indexes on `datum` and `Plek#`.

Comment: Well, if you just pulling one value, then dlookup() is as fast a recordset. However, if you need 10 columns, then a recodset to pull the one record will be 10x faster. You not made it clear that you were or are to use dlookup() to pull more then one value. If you need all columns from one record, then one sql pull + a reocrdset will be "x" times faster based on the number of columns. No where was the suggestion here is you need more then one value from a given table.